# ID variable based on combination of variables

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a data frame that is arranged as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(NAME1=  c("AAA","CCC","BBB","BBB"), 
                 NAME2    =  c("BBB", "AAA","DDD","AAA"),
                 AMT      = c(40,20,10,50)),.Names=c("NAME1","NAME2","AMT"), 
                 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class =("data.frame"))
```

I would like to create an ID variable as a combination of character variables NAME1 and NAME2 regardless of the order (i.e. AAA BBB is the same as BBB AAA) and sum up AMT.

This is what I would like to end up with:

```
df <- structure(list(NAME1 =  c("AAA","CCC", "BBB"), 
                 NAME2     =  c("BBB", "AAA","DDD"),
                 AMT       =  c(90,20,10),
                 ID        =  c(1,2,3)),
                 .Names    =  c("NAME1","NAME2","AMT","ID"), 
                 row.names =  c("1", "2", "3"), class =("data.frame"))
```

Your inputs would be much appreciated.

Comment: if any of the answers below solved your issue please consider accepting it as an answer by clicking on the check mark. This lets the community know the answer worked and that your issue is closed.

Answer (score 2):

You could create two new grouping variables that order the values across rows so that `AAA, BBB` and `BBB, AAA` are treated the same (because they get put in the same order). Afterwards, grouping operations are simple enough. I chose to use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

df[,c("NAME1_o","NAME2_o")] <- t(apply(cbind(df$NAME1, df$NAME2), 1, function(x) x[order(x)]))
setDT(df)[, .(AMT = sum(AMT), ID = .GRP), by = .(NAME1_o, NAME2_o)]

#   NAME1_o NAME2_o AMT ID
#1:     AAA     BBB  90  1
#2:     AAA     CCC  20  2
#3:     BBB     DDD  10  3
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks for your input. I tried that on on my data and have been getting a bunch of warning messages like  1: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , c("NAME1_o", "NAME2_o"), value = c("BBB",  :
  2 column matrix RHS of := will be treated as one vector
2: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , c("NAME1_o", "NAME2_o"), value = c("BBB",  :
  Supplied 3583438 items to be assigned to 1791719 items of column 'NAME1_o' (1791719 unused).  What I get eventually is like this                
 BBB     BBB   somenumber1  1
 CCC    CCC   somenumber2  2
 Any suggestions?

Comment: In the first step with `df[,c(...)]`, `df` needs to be a `data.frame`, not a `data.table`. I assumed you had a `df` as an input since that's what you posted in your sample data

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. I just rearranged the data as a _data.frame_ and I no longer get the warnings and the combinations seem fine. If I wanted to save the output as a new _data.frame_, it would be fine to just do _data <- setDT(df)[, .(AMT = sum(AMT), ID = .GRP), by = .(NAME1_o, NAME2_o)]_ ?

Comment: @korone No, what that `setDT` does is convert the `data.frame` to a `data.table` so if you wanted to use that syntax and have a data frame output you would need to convert it back. Alternatively you could do the group-by using `data.frame` syntax. There are a lot of SO answers already out there on this

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` verbs:

```
df %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(PAIR=paste0(sort(c(NAME1,NAME2)),collapse=" ")) %>% 
   group_by(PAIR) %>% 
   summarise(AMT=sum(AMT)) %>%
   mutate(ID=row_number()) %>%
   separate(PAIR, " ", into=c("NAME1","NAME2"))

  NAME1 NAME2   AMT    ID
1   AAA   BBB    90     1
2   AAA   CCC    20     2
3   BBB   DDD    10     3
```